# Column sorting not working with nth-child "background-color" (two conflicting background colors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

This should be really easy for me to figure out but its been taking me literally hours at this point, so I could definitely use some help here.

Basically I have a sortable stat table of `<tr><td></td></tr>` elements. The table can be found [here](http://www.primordia.pw/mlb/players/hernafe02.html).

When I click on any of the categories at the top, it is suppossed to drop-down a full yellow highlight box over the entire column of statistics. It worked fine until I put a

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

element into my `*.css` to get the light gray backgrounds on all the even rows.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I have two conflicting background-colors, one in the css that I just showed above and the one that makes the columns highlight as yellow. I just need to make sure the yellow row always goes on top (if thats even possible)

Also, [here](http://www.primordia.pw/mlb/players/saundmi01.html) is a link that properly demonstrates how the column highlighter is supposed to work. Its currently running off its own separate `*.css`

And for anyone wondering, yes I am new to html, I've only been doing stuff like this for the last week or two.

Comment: Can you provide a code example that demonstrates the problem you face, preferrably in a Stackoverflow code snippet or a JSFiddle or Codepen?

Comment: Half of the question is missing - the css that makes the column yellow and how it is applied.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a precedence system. Every selector is given a score according to how specific it is, and highest score wins. Tag gets 1 point, class name gets 10 points, and id gets 100 points.

So, for example, `#mytable > tr > td.even` would get 112 points.

If you make the yellow column selector more specific than the even/odd rows selector, it will win and you'll see the yellow background you want.

If you want to get a better understanding, there are many resources on how this actually works, and there are workarounds for edge cases as well. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), for example.

Comment: This "precedence system" does in fact have a name: *Specificity*.

Comment: I've been working with this system but I'm still very confused.. Heres both .css pieces for the grey rows and the yellow column bars `tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}` and then `.sortable .sort_col {
    background-color:#ffa;border:solid 2px #747678;
}` @NimrodArgov

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

### saundmi01.html

- Missing closing `</head>` tag
- Missing opening `<body>` tag
- Add quotes to `<div id=page_container>` tag.

### hernafe02.html

- Move closing `</head>` and opening `<body>` tag above the `<div id=page_container>` tag.
- Add quotes to `<div id=page_container>` tag.

---

## CSS

The stylesheet is dynamically loaded into the head. It is a nightmare...***433 `!important`s!!!*** I've never seen so many in one stylesheet before. It's safe to assume that if you want to change, add, and/or remove any styles, you'll need to either:

1. Add a ruleset to the bottom of the [external stylesheet](http://www.primordia.pw/mlb/teams/SEA/SEA_player.css). This is by far the best option.

#### OR

2. Add a `<style>` block in the body because the dynamically loaded stylesheet appends to the head. Then place new styles in there and add `!important` to anything that doesn't work.

#### OR

3. Place styles inline which involves adding styles to each element individually. I won't bother to go into any details on that option, because it shouldn't really be considered.

---

## OPTION #2

After correcting the HTML previously mentioned, add a `<style>` block below the opening `<body>` tag and above the `div.page_container`:

```
</head>
<body>

<style>

</style>

<div id="page_container">
```

Next, place the following ruleset inside the `<style>` block:

```
</head>
<body>

<style>
    .stats_table tr:nth-child(even) {
         background-color: #0ff; 
    }
</style>

<div id="page_container">
```

Taking these steps should guarantee control over your table's even ordered rows. If that doesn't work, add `!important` or double up classes and add a tag (ex. `table.stats_table.stats_table`). If you want the highest specificity possible try this monster:

> `table.stats_table.stats_table.sortable.sortable.row_summable.row_summable > tbody > tr.full.full { background-color: #00ffff !important; }`

This selector has a specificity of 12 according to this [online tool](http://johannesneumeier.com/tools/specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
.stat_average, .stat_total:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f1f1f1};
```

why because in `tfoot` there are 3 `tr`(table rows) so you given `nth-child(even)` so there is no content in even row i mean in second row that is the issue i found.
Please try above code it may help you.